# A colon after "following"

Tags: punctuation, colons, periods

When I reference to the next sentence or sentences using the term *following*, is the preferred way to use a colon or a full stop?

An example:

> Consider the sentence 'I wash the clothes'. Replacing the letter *h* with the letter *o* in the previous sentence results in the following sentence. I waso toe clotoes.

Comment: (1) I sometimes think that the use of both a colon and the word “following” is awkward because they mean the same thing.  But I often use both anyway because many people do so.  I hope that some answers to this question shed light on this dilemma.  (2) In my opinion, the first sentence should be something like the following for better readability: “Consider a sentence ‘I wash the clothes.’”  Writing “I wash the clothes.” as a bare sentence seems strange because you are only [mentioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) this sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colon.

Using a period misses the opportunity to connect the two sentences.

Of course, avoid overusing colons in your writing.