# Is this correct English? What should one do when you're supposed to have *two* punctuations at *one* position?

Tags: punctuation, british-english, question-mark, colons

> This is the first sentence of which
>   ground-breaking document:
>
> "The importance of a Web page is an
>   inherently subjective matter, which
>   depends on the readers interests,
>   knowledge and attitudes."

In the paragraph above, is "This is... document" correct English? Also, *theoretically*, shouldn't there be *two* punctuations after "document", a colon, and a question mark, since it's a question. What do you do in such a case?

Possibly related question: [A colon after "following"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/a-colon-after-following)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is there a problem with the English?*
As a question, the English is fine.

*Should there be a colon and a question-mark at the end of the first line?*
No, the question mark belongs after the quotation.

*What if the quote is a page long?*
Reword the question: "The following is the first page of which ground-breaking document?"

I note that this rewording does now somewhat resurrect the question in the title, but the question mark now dominates here IMHO.

Comment: What if the "quotation" is a page long?

Answer (score 0):

The wording is fine.

I'd try to reword it. If I had to word it that way, I'd put a question mark after the intro, no colon.